# PHPMYADMIN master slave replication

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, centos

Hey guys I am working on building a new environment for a customer. we have 2 app servers and 2 database mysql servers. They are running centos7. the two database severs run a master slave replication. Each app server has apache, php and will have phpmyadmin. My question is in this setup how would phpmyadmin work, should I configure phpmyadmin to point to the master server or how whould that work?

Comment: If you want to update the database, you need to do it on the master server. You can use either the master or slave if you just want to view the contents.

Comment: That is kind of what I was thinking.